# Python HTTPConnectionPool Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, pool

I was wondering if my requests is stopped by the website and I need to set a proxy.I first try to close the http's connection ,bu I failed.I also try to test my code but now it seems no outputs.Mybe I use a proxy everything will be OK?
Here is the code.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from multiprocessing import Pool
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
import time


def get_page_index(offset, keyword):
    #headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/534.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.50'}
    data = {
        'offset': offset,
        'format': 'json',
        'keyword': keyword,
        'autoload': 'true',
        'count': 20,
        'cur_tab': 1
    }
    url = 'http://www.toutiao.com/search_content/?' + urlencode(data)
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'Connection': 'close'})
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.text
        return None
    except RequestException as e:
        print(e)

def parse_page_index(html):
    data = json.loads(html)
    if data and 'data' in data.keys():
        for item in data.get('data'):
            url = item.get('article_url')
            if url and len(url) < 100:
                yield url

def get_page_detail(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'Connection': 'close'})
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.text
        return None
    except RequestException as e:
        print(e)

def parse_page_detail(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title = soup.select('title')[0].get_text()
    pattern = re.compile(r'articleInfo: (.*?)},', re.S)
    pattern_abstract = re.compile(r'abstract: (.*?)\.', re.S)
    res = re.search(pattern, html)
    res_abstract = re.search(pattern_abstract, html)
    if res and res_abstract:
        data = res.group(1).replace(r".replace(/<br \/>|\n|\r/ig, '')", "") + '}'
        abstract = res_abstract.group(1).replace(r"'", "")
        content = re.search(r'content: (.*?),', data).group(1)
        source = re.search(r'source: (.*?),', data).group(1)
        time_pattern = re.compile(r'time: (.*?)}', re.S)
        date = re.search(time_pattern, data).group(1)
        date_today = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        img = re.findall(r'src=&quot;(.*?)&quot', content)
        if date[1:11] == date_today and len(content) > 50 and img:
            return {
                'title': title,
                'content': content,
                'source': source,
                'date': date,
                'abstract': abstract,
                'img': img[0]
            }

def main(offset):
    flag = 1
    html = get_page_index(offset, '光伏')
    for url in parse_page_index(html):
        html = get_page_detail(url)
        if html:
            data = parse_page_detail(html)
            if data:
                html_parser = HTMLParser()
                cwl = html_parser.unescape(data.get('content'))
                data['content'] = cwl
                print(data)
                print(data.get('img'))
                flag += 1
                if flag == 5:
                    break



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(main, [i*20 for i in range(10)])
```

and the error is the here!

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='tech.jinghua.cn', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /zixun/20160720/f191549.shtml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000000048523C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

By the way, When I test my code at first it shows everything is OK!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I test my code again.I get the outputs but will stop when I meet the error HTTPConnectionPool, is there any way to solve this Interruption.Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems to me you're hitting the limit of connection in the HTTPConnectionPool. Since you start 10 threads at the same time

Try one of the following:

1. Increase the request timeout (seconds): `requests.get('url', timeout=5)`
2. Close the response: `Response.close()`. Instead of returning response.text, assign response to a varialble, close Response, and then return variable

Comment: `response.close()`

Answer (score 4):

When I faced this issue I had the following problems

I wasn't able to do the following
- The requests python module was unable to get information from any url. Although I was able to surf the site with browser, also could get wget or curl to download that page.
- pip install  was also not working and use to fail with following errors

`Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`

Certain site blocked me so i tried forcebindip to use another network interface for my python modules and then i removed it. Probably that cause my network to mess up and my request module and even the direct socket module were stuck and not able to fetch any url.

So I followed network configuration reset in the below URL and now I am good.

[network configuration reset](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6653#7vista)

Answer (score 2):

**In case it helps someone else, I faced this same error message:**

```
Client-Request-ID=long-string Retry policy did not allow for a retry: , HTTP status code=Unknown, Exception=HTTPSConnectionPool(host='table.table.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /service(PartitionKey='requests',RowKey='9999') (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D920ADA970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')).
```

...when trying to retrieve a record from Azure Table Storage using

`table_service.get_entity(table_name, partition_key, row_key)`.

**My issue:**

- I had the `table_name` incorrectly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's due to a VPN connection. I had the same problem. I wasn't even capable of installing the package `requests` via pip. I turned off my VPN and voilà, I managed to install it and also to make requests. The `[Errno 11004]` code was gone.

Answer (score -1):

My structural URL was incorrect (after ".com" there was no slash and there was a coupling of another part of the url)